# Rotation of braces

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can I rotate a brace to make it appear [this way](https://www.google.tn/search?q=brace&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PLR4U8GJKqqa1AX_yYCADQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=799#q=accolade&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=lQwPEhMBB1OPTM%253A%3BVXzKAlXQGgDRrM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmont-des-cats.pagesperso-orange.fr%252Fimages%252Faccolade2.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmont-des-cats.pagesperso-orange.fr%252Fhesse.html%3B237%3B958)?

I'm currently using this code:

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace}][scale=2] 
\node [rotate=270] (A) {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont A}; 
\node [fit=(A)] (fit) {};              
\draw [decorate,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=7pt]fit.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `decoration={brace,mirror}` what you're looking for?

Comment: @eiterorm, that've worked, thank you ^^. Would you write it as an answer or do I delete this question instead?

Comment: Don't do `[<first optional arg>][<second optional arg>]`, but `[<first optional arg>, <second optional arg>]`.

Comment: You can also reverse the coordinates like  `\draw [decorate,line width=1pt]
  ([yshift=-7pt]fit.north west) -- ([yshift=7pt]fit.south west);`. Note that with a rotation of 270 degrees, your yshifts have to be interchanged too.

Comment: can you include the picture in your post? A link to google of a nice painting is not what you mean, do you?

Answer (score 1):

CW from the comments:

Use the `mirror` key as part of `decoration` to mirror the decoration along the path. The result here produces an ugly shortened brace, but I'm assuming the actual use case has more content so this problem goes away.

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace,mirror}][scale=2] 
\node [rotate=270] (A) {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont A}; 
\node [fit=(A)] (fit) {};              
\draw [decorate,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=7pt]fit.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]